# Somewhere to download CSS coverflow?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, css, coverflow

This is my favorite coverflow:
http://paulbakaus.com/lab/js/coverflow/

Is there some way to download this? Or is there an implementation guide?

All I see are some blog posts with nothing on how to implement.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

How about downloading all the scripts in the source?

```
<html> 
    <head> 
        <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> 
        <title>Coverflow featuring css transitions</title> 
        <style type="text/css" media="screen"> 
            body,html {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                background: #000;
                height: 100%;
                color: #eee;
                font-family: Arial;
                font-size: 10px;
            }

            h1 {
                margin: 20px;
            }

            p {
                margin: 20px;
            }

            div.magnifyme {
                height: 80px;
                padding: 30px;
                position: absolute;
                top: 0px;
                left: 0px;
                width: 2000px;
            }

            div.wrapper {
                margin: 20px;
                height: 160px;
                border: 2px solid #999;
                overflow: hidden;
                width: 600px;
                position: relative;
            }

            div.slider {
                position: absolute;
                bottom: 5px;
                left: 30px;
                width: 542px;
                height: 19px;
                background: url(productbrowser_scrollbar_20070622.png) no-repeat;
            }

            div.ui-slider-handle {
                position: absolute;
                cursor: pointer;
                cursor: hand;
                top: 0px;
                left: 0px;
                height: 100%;
                width: 181px;
                background: url(handle.png) no-repeat;

            }

            div.magnifyme img {
                width: 64px;
                height: 64px;
                float: left;
                margin: 5px;
                position: relative;
                border: 1px solid #999;
            }
        </style> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.2.6.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="ui.core.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="ui.slider.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="effects.core.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="ui.coverflow.js"></script> 

<script type="text/javascript" src="../transformie/sylvester.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="../transformie/pb.transformie.js"></script> 



        <script type="text/javascript"> 
            $(document).ready(function() {

                $("div.magnifyme").coverflow();

            });

        </script> 
    </head> 
    <body> 

    <h1>Coverflow effect featuring CSS transformations and jQuery UI</h1> 

    <p> 
        This proof-of-concept shows a coverflow effect using the new CSS transformation feature from Webkit (featured in Safari 3.1). Needless
        to say that it won't run in other browsers at this point (however, adapting it to canvas should be quite easy, and even now, it won't break in other browsers).
    </p> 

    <p> 
        Unlike other demos, this one can truly animate between two half states, making a slider implementation like the iTunes slider really easy (will come
        to this demo soon!). Have fun and try using the keyboard for hotness ;)
    </p> 

<div class="wrapper"> 
    <div class="magnifyme"> 
        <img src="icons/1.png" /> 
        <img src="icons/2.png" /> 
        <img src="icons/3.png" /> 
        <img src="icons/4.png" /> 
        <img src="icons/5.png" /> 
        <img src="icons/6.png" /> 
        <img src="icons/7.png" /> 
        <img src="icons/8.png" /> 
        <img src="icons/9.png" /> 
        <img src="icons/10.png" /> 
        <img src="icons/1.png" /> 
        <img src="icons/2.png" /> 
        <img src="icons/3.png" /> 
        <img src="icons/4.png" /> 
        <img src="icons/5.png" /> 
        <img src="icons/6.png" /> 
        <img src="icons/7.png" /> 
        <img src="icons/8.png" /> 
        <img src="icons/9.png" /> 
        <img src="icons/10.png" /> 
    </div> 
    <div class="slider"> 
        <div class="ui-slider-handle"></div> 
    </div> 
</div> 
    </body> 
</html>
```

Just replace the `<img>` elements in the element and it should provide the same functionality.

As an example one of the scripts is @ http://paulbakaus.com/lab/js/coverflow/ui.coverflow.js

Comment: The script specifically says //THIS IS FOR DEMO PURPOSES ONLY!

Comment: @Mark - Perhaps the reason why you can't find any documentation on it or even a download is that it's not a finished product.

Comment: It works pretty well. Is the license OS? Someone should release it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you just looking for a site riiper which will duplicate the web site on your PC? If so, look here http://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-web-site-ripper.htm  (and look at that site always for the best in free s/w).

**CAVEAT** ask the site owner before ripping.